# Select data from table with update if particular row does not exist

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple table TBL consisting of two columns Err_type and Val.
Need to select all date from it. Seems to be simple, but it gets uglier when particular row does not exist.

```
with cte as (
select TBL.Err_type, TBL.Val from TBL
where TBL.Err_type = 4 or TBL.Err_type = 2
)

select * from cte
```

There are possibilities that "4" or "2" might not exist in given datetime range. So i need to insert the missing row ("4" or "2" for Err_type and "0" for Val) and then get the table.

e.g.

```
 Err_type | Val     
 ---------------
     4    | 50
     2    |  0
```

instead of

```
 Err_type | Val     
 ---------------
     4    | 50
```

Comment: If there is Err_types table, left join that table to TBL. If not, create one so you would at least have some descriptions for these codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following sql that will check for existence of record and if not found then insert.

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   TBL 
         WHERE  TBL.Err_Type IN ( 4, 2 ) 
         UNION 
         SELECT 4, 
                0 
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                            FROM   TBL 
                            WHERE  TBL.Err_Type = 4) 
         UNION 
         SELECT 2, 
                0 
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                            FROM   TBL 
                            WHERE  TBL.Err_Type = 2)) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte
```

Comment: You may also need to insert `TBL.Val` if there's not a default value of zero.

Comment: But still there is a problem. I get an error "Incorrect syntax near Select. Expected AS, ID or Quoted_ID. I simply added your script before "select * from cte".

Comment: Something is wrong with the computer i am working right now...  ![ ][1]  
 
[1]: http://i47.tinypic.com/2zzswaw.png